# How to parse every second row into the second column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parse a text file into two columns. The file follows the structure of two addresses at a time where the first address needs to go into the first column and the second address into the second column. This then needs to be repeated for every two address after the comments line (`########################`)

The structure looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_clipboard('''
Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310-246-1501 Steakhouses


Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310/246-1501 American
########################

Art's Deli 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City 818-762-1221 Delis


Art's Delicatessen 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City 818/762-1221 American
########################

Bel-Air Hotel 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air 310-472-1211 Californian


Hotel Bel-Air 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air 310/472-1211 Californian
########################

Cafe Bizou 14016 Ventura Blvd. Sherman Oaks 818-788-3536 French Bistro


Cafe Bizou 14016 Ventura Blvd. Sherman Oaks 818/788-3536 French
########################

Campanile 624 S. La Brea Ave. Los Angeles 213-938-1447 Californian


Campanile 624 S. La Brea Ave. Los Angeles 213/938-1447 American
''',  comment='#')
```

I need to parse the file into a pandas dataframe that looks like this (example for first two addresses):

```html
'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>address1</th>\n      <th>address2</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>Arnie Morton\'s of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310-246-1501 Steakhouses</td>\n      <td>Arnie Morton\'s of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310/246-1501 American</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I follow the clipboard part, but from your string example, here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lines = """...your lines..."""
# strip empty lines and comments
data = np.array([s for s in 
      (l for l in s.split('\n') if len(l) and not l.startswith('#'))
])
# create the dataframe, using np.reshape to create 2 columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape((-1,2)), columns=['addr_1', 'addr_2'])
```

This will work as long as the structure is consistent: the addresses are always two-by-two, all comments start with '#', empty lines are really empty (don't have space).